# how to loop through each rows and column values in google sheet using app script?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

am trying to loop through all the amount values in google sheet using app script , but am when i use for loop am only able to get "aoumnt 1" column values only ,

```
  var sheetSource1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
var activecell = sheetSource1.getRange(i + 2, 2).getValue();
Logger.log(activecell);
}
```

when i run Logger.log()
i get like below

> 

- 860
- 650
- 420

but i want to reesult like

- 860
- 650
- 420
- 760
- 550
- 525

how to achive this result.?

Comment: Please, post the code you used to loop over it

Comment: i have code posted.. brother

Answer (score 1):

So, when you iterate over using `getValue` you need to Loop twice:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetSource1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
      var activecell = sheetSource1.getRange(j + 3, i + 1).getValue();
      Logger.log(activecell);
    }
  }
}
```

But a nested `for` is not the best perfomance or practice.
Then, we can use `getValues()` to return an array of arrays (multi dimensional 2d array). And from there iterate over the entire range as an unique source:

```js
function myFunctionT() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let numCols = 2;
  let numRows = 3;
  var range = data.getRange(4, 2, numRows, numCols).getValues(); // <- using getValues(), and getRange can have multiple types of parameters to get ranges
  let col1 = [];
  let col2 = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var row = range[i];
    var firstColValue = row[0];
    var secondColValue = row[1];
    col1.push(firstColValue);
    col2.push(secondColValue);
  }

  let list = [...col1, ...col2];
  Logger.log(list)

}
```